# A question on counting the almost (!) injective monotone functions of two sets

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let's define a function almost injective $f: A \rightarrow B$ if for every $b \in B$ the number of elements with $f(a) = b$ is at most $2$. Let $M(n)$ be the number of almost injective monotone functions from a set $[n]$ to itself $[n] \rightarrow [n]$. How to compute $M(n)$ in a general case?
Or as an example for $M(5)$?

Comment: [n]????????????

Comment: $$[n] = \{1, …, n\}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As clarified in comments, you want the function to be weakly increasing.

To map $k$ pairs to the same element, you can choose $\binom{n-k}k$ positions for the $k$ pairs among the $k+(n-2k)=n-k$ pairs and singletons, and then you can choose $\binom n{n-k}$ values for the $n-k$ pairs and singletons, for a total of

$$
M(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\binom n{n-k}\binom{n-k}k=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\frac{n!}{(n-2k)!k!^2}
$$

functions. You could reach the same result by choosing $k$ values with zero preimages, $k$ values with two preimages and $n-2k$ values with one preimage.

In your example,

$$
M(5)=5!\left(\frac1{5!}+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{2!^2}\right)=1+20+30=51\;.
$$

---

This is the answer I originally posted, when I'd overlooked the word “monotone”.

If $k$ pairs of elements are mapped to the same element, there are $\binom n{2k}$ ways to choose those elements, $\frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!}$ ways to group them into pairs, and $\frac{n!}{k!}$ ways to map the $k+(n-2k)=n-k$ pairs and singletons to different elements. Thus, the total number of almost injective functions from $[n]$ to $[n]$ is

$$
M(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}\frac{n!^2}{2^k(n-2k)!k!^2}\;.
$$

In your example,

$$
M(5)=5!^2\left(\frac1{5!}+\frac1{2\cdot3!}+\frac1{4\cdot2!^2}\right)=2220\;.
$$

Comment: Good explanations thank you a lot! I'm doing these exercises for an online course in discrete maths. But the validations of the exercise tells me, that it's wrong. I'm trying to recalculate based on your suggestion and then I'll report!

Comment: @JohnSmith: Sorry, I overlooked "monotone" in the question. I'll add that in a bit.

Comment: The monotone criterion should change the ways of choosing the pairs to $n - (k -1)$ possibilities? Just involving the neighbors of an element?

Comment: @JohnSmith: Do you mean strictly or weakly monotone? And can it be either increasing or decreasing?

Comment: I think it should be weakly monotone. In this specific case weakly increasing.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I corrected the answer; I hope it now reflects what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes thats it! I had somehow the error with $n-(k-1)$ instead of $n-k$. That was my mistake. Thank you a lot!